# Maven can not authorize when fetching from AWS Codeartifact

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven-3, aws-codeartifact

I have created an Codeartifact repository with the instruction from AWS. Also I had a user with the admin Codeartifact policy -> linked to codeartifact. I can upload and store packages on Codeartifact but unfortunately i get always with mvn clean install an 401 not authorized.

**full codefactory policy**

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
                "arn:aws:iam::******:user/***",
                "arn:aws:iam::******:root"
            ]
        },
        "Action": [
            "codeartifact:AssociateExternalConnection",
            "codeartifact:CopyPackageVersions",
            "codeartifact:DeletePackageVersions",
            "codeartifact:DeletePackage",
            "codeartifact:DeleteRepository",
            "codeartifact:DeleteRepositoryPermissionsPolicy",
            "codeartifact:DescribePackageVersion",
            "codeartifact:DescribeRepository",
            "codeartifact:DisassociateExternalConnection",
            "codeartifact:DisposePackageVersions",
            "codeartifact:GetPackageVersionReadme",
            "codeartifact:GetRepositoryEndpoint",
            "codeartifact:ListPackageVersionAssets",
            "codeartifact:ListPackageVersionDependencies",
            "codeartifact:ListPackageVersions",
            "codeartifact:ListPackages",
            "codeartifact:PublishPackageVersion",
            "codeartifact:PutPackageMetadata",
            "codeartifact:PutRepositoryPermissionsPolicy",
            "codeartifact:ReadFromRepository",
            "codeartifact:UpdatePackageVersionsStatus",
            "codeartifact:UpdateRepository"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

**full iam role **

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Action": [
            "codeartifact:*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "sts:GetServiceBearerToken",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "sts:AWSServiceName": "codeartifact.amazonaws.com"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

**maven settings.xml**

```
<settings>

  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>codeartifact</id>
      <username>aws</username>
      <password>${env.CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN}</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>codeartifact</id>
          <name>CodeArtifact Plugins</name>
          <url>https://***-***.d.codeartifact.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/maven/****/</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>default</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>central-mirror</id>
      <name>CodeArtifact Maven Central mirror</name>
      <url>https://***-***.d.codeartifact.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/maven/****/</url>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
</settings>
```

**POM xml create for demo via spring initializr**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.techpilot</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>codeartifact</id>
            <name>codeartifact</name>
            <url>https://***-***.d.codeartifact.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/maven/***</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

what also have done is that i check my aws credentials with my account and its the same aws_access_key_id from the user which i have given that policy. Everything works with publishing to the repo (Bitbucket aswell) but i cannot recieve anything from that repository i tried every solution i found... nothing new

Exception always the same

```
Authentication failed for https://***-***.d.codeartifact.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/maven/***/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/3.1.4/spring-boot-starter-parent-3.1.4.pom 401 Unauthorized
```